# How to extract load and displacement data for all steps on a particular node/node set using ABAQUS python scripting (without consuming licence)?

Tags: python, abaqus

In ABAQUS, I want to extract loads ['RF'] and displacements ['U'] values ('Field Outputs') for all steps on a particular node/node set (let's call the node set as 'N100') by using python scripting.

I am already doing it by using a script with sessions objects (generated from .rpy file generated during ABAQUS CAE session). The command I use for execution is 'ABAQUS CAE NOGUI=SCRIPT.py'. It consumes a licence as it is using ABAQUS CAE.

My condition is that, I want to extract **'field output'** results (loads ['RF'] and displacements ['U']) for all steps on node set 'N100' **without consuming a licence**. i.e. by using **'odbAccess'** library.

I have found some description related to it in ABAQUS documentation
( http://dsk.ippt.pan.pl/docs/abaqus/v6.13/books/cmd/default.htm?startat=pt05ch09s05.html ).
But, I am unable to find a solution that works for my needs.The script given in ABAQUS documentation extracts load and displacement results **only on the last step** *and* that too **for all the nodes** in the ODB file. I want to extract results for **all step times (not just last)** and on a **particular node/ node set.**
(lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1])

The script given in ABAQUS documentation works without consuming any licence.

Can anyone guide me for the same ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? See: [mcve].

Comment: from odbAccess import *
odb=openOdb(path='Job-1.odb')
myAssembly=odb.rootAssembly
topNodeSet1=odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['N100']
lastFrame=odb.steps['Step-2'].frames[-1]
displacement=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['U']
fieldValues=displacement.values
dispFile1 = open('Node.csv','w+')
for v in fieldValues :
 dispFile1.write('Node=%dU[x]=%6.4f,U[y]=%6.4f\n'%(v.nodeLabel,v.data[0],v.data[1]))
dispFile1.close()
#I have copy-pested fromdocumentation and modified it slightly as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

The following extracts 'RF' and 'U' of all nodes for all simulation frames.

```
    part_instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1']
    for key in keys:
    step = odb.steps[key]
    frameRepository = step.frames
    if len(frameRepository):
        for frame in frameRepository:
            print 'Id = %d, Time = %f\n'%(frame.frameId,frame.frameValue)
            fo = frame.fieldOutputs
            f1 = fo['U']
            f2 = fo['RF2']
```

Now you just need to filter f1 and f2 variables for the specific node that you are interested in. A simple print statement to understand the structure of f1 and f2 can really help you.